Explanation for extra move constructor call
I will straightaway head to the code and explain what I'm trying to understand here.
class MyInt 
{
    unique_ptr<int> ptr;
    public:
        MyInt(int val)
        { 
            cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "this: <" << this << ">, val: <" << val << ">" << endl;
            ptr = make_unique<int>(val);
        }
        ~MyInt()
        {
            cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "this: <" << this << ">" << endl;
        }
       
        MyInt(MyInt&& other) noexcept: ptr(move(other.ptr))
        { 
            cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "this: <" << this << ">, other :<" << &other << ">" << endl;
        }

        MyInt& operator=(MyInt&& other) noexcept
        { 
            cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "this: <" << this << ">, other :<" << &other << ">" << endl;
            if (this != &other)
            {
                ptr = move(other.ptr);
                other.ptr = nullptr;
            }

            return *this;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyInt *aptr = new MyInt[2]{11, 22};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        cout << "aptr[" << i << "] :" << &aptr[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "deleting :" << endl;
    
    delete [] aptr;

    cout << "exiting" << endl;

    return 0;

}
ouput of this code is :
onkar@DESKTOP-MTXXX:~/CppDesignPatterns/build$ ./DesignPatterns/Test
MyInt::MyInt(int)this: <0x7ffe7a274e30>, val: <11>
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x7ffe7a274e50>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e30>
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x603000000048>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e50>
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x7ffe7a274e50>
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x7ffe7a274e30>
MyInt::MyInt(int)this: <0x7ffe7a274e70>, val: <22>
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x7ffe7a274e90>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e70>
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x603000000050>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e90>
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x7ffe7a274e90>
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x7ffe7a274e70>
aptr[0] :0x603000000048
aptr[1] :0x603000000050
deleting :
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x603000000050>
MyInt::~MyInt()this: <0x603000000048>
exiting
onkar@DESKTOP-MTXXX:~/CppDesignPatterns/build$

From the above code and output, it is straightforward for anyone to understand that temporary object is created, memory is allocated and the temporary object is moved to the appropriate location in the memory for the array aptr.
what I'm failing to understand here are the extra calls -
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x7ffe7a274e50>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e30>

and
MyInt::MyInt(MyInt&&)this: <0x7ffe7a274e90>, other :<0x7ffe7a274e70>

Why are these calls happening ? What's the purpose (or maybe likely purpose) ?
BTW, the flags I'm passing to CMake to build this code is
# Set C++ standards 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Disable copy elision, RVO -fno-elide-constructors
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address -fno-elide-constructors -g")

that is copy elision is disabled.

dont spam tags. For which c++ version are you actually compiling?

other.ptr = nullptr; is unnecessary.  endl should be "\n", since the other thing endl does is unnecessary (and a pessimization).

Not reproducing it. what compiler and compile options are used? What standard? Output wastly differentiates depending on that. From some point side-effects are even UB. It looks like extra move happens due creation of {11,22} which is obsolete - it can be constructed in-place.

C++14 and g++ compiler. I used with -fno-elide-constructors with g++

-fno-elide-constructors. It disables standard behaviour to elide constructor calls (not an optimization) In that case there is a list created {11,22}, which then gets moved during array initialization.

@Swift-FridayPie - What you are saying is, list is created first and then moved during initialization into (heap allocated [using new])
array, is it ?

worse, first each gets created individually, then they moved to temporal storage of list, and then moved to array. That's not stanard behaviour. That flag mostly is meant for debugging or finding compatibility issues during code base upgrade

@Swift-FridayPie -fno-elide-constructors only disables optional copy elision (i.e., NRVO in C++17 as well as regular copy elision before) and should be standard conforming

@Artyer it avoids optional elision AND forces copy\move constructors to be called at all times (from description). The latter doesn't contradict standard, because it leaves that undefined.

"I will straightaway head to the code" -- Are you aware that [ask] advises the opposite? Questions that rely on code to define the problem tend to be harder to understand. (Especially when the code is non-trivial and I don't know which details I should be focusing on.)

"it is straightforward for anyone to understand that" -- For anyone? This is rather dismissive of the people who don't understand what you are doing. Perhaps the people who can answer your question would find this understanding to be straightforward, but what about other people with similar questions? Do you really want to come across as an elitist who dismisses those with inferior knowledge? Side note: if you moved this explanation before your code and made it a goal instead of an observation, then the dismissive tone might organically disappear.

-fno-elide-constructors removes guaranteed elision. That is creation of object happens in several steps:
Create temporal MyInt (11) 
Move MyInt (11) to instance inside of temporal initialization list.
Move MyInt (11) to 1st element of array 
Create temporal MyInt (22)
Move MyInt (22) to instance inside of temporal initialization list.
Move MyInt (22) to 2nd element of array 

The standard behaviour is to construct array elements right where they are created, not how the expression graph goes:
Create 1st element of array MyInt (11)
Create 2nd element of array MyInt (22)

In both cases initialization of 1st array element is sequenced before 2nd element, therefore the "as if" rule isn't broken. Imagine if constructors were relying on some external state (e.g. counting number of existing objects) to initialize value, the result would be same regardless if you used -fno-elide-constructors or not. A similar side-effect in a copy or move costructor would result in different effects, but standard offers no guarantees in that case.

temporal initialization list - you mean temporal list with 2 elements ? You can see that the temporal address (0x7ffe7a274e50) is freed after moving the object to heap location (0x603000000048) before calling the 22 ctor.

@OnkarNMahajan yeas, but it isn't requred materialize as such, while there is  requrement to finish initailizatin of 1st element before starting 2nd, therefore it's such an odd order. Initialization lists are abstract lexical construct, not true objects. Not to be mistaken with std::initializer_list
